# How can i write the zipcode validation by selected country in magento checokut page.?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

For Ex:in Checkout Page 
selected country - USA
Zipcode - 500018

if 500018 is not available in USA show an error like "Please Enter Valid Zip code" or "This Zipcode is Not availble in Selected Country".

Comment: please refer this https://community.magento.com/t5/Admin-Configuration-Questions/ZIP-Code-Validation/td-p/33351

Comment: Thanks a lot,its uses for only zipcode length validation.but i need entered zipcode is not their in USA its shows an error message..